# error detection on food packaging -using Open Cv

Tags: opencv, computer-vision

I am trying to determine when a food packaging have error or not error. Example 
the logo  " McDonald's " have error misprints or not, as the wrong label, wrong color..( i can not post picture )
What should I do, please help me!!

Comment: This is a research problem and you should know what you need to do at least. There are a number of possible answers to your question that you should study and examine.

Comment: i am studing,but time is limit ,deadline is 1 month.Can you suggest some methods?

Answer (score 1):

It's not a trivial task by any stretch of the imagination. Two images of the same identical object will always be different according to lightning conditions, perspective, shooting angle, etc.

Basically you need to:
1. Process the 2 images into "digested" data - dominant color, shapes, etcw
2. Design and run your own similarity algorithm between the 2 objects

You may want to look at Feature detectors in OpenCV: Surf, SIFT, etc.

Comment: Ok,I put the package on a conveyor belt, with the same conditions as light ,perspective, shooting angle,etc.
I use SURF,but I don't finish.

Answer (score 0):

Along a result I just found your question, so I think I come too late.

If not I think your problem car easily be resolved, it exists since years and is called [***Sikuli***](http://www.sikuli.org/) .

While it's for testing purposes, I have been using it in the same way as you need : compare a reference and a production image. Based on OpenCV it does it very well.